# Как дать доступ к бд в другом пк?

Tags: c#, mysql

Объясните плиз вот у меня есть приложение на C# и бд составленная на субд MySQL Workbench и вот у меня такой вопрос как дать доступ к бд на другом пк если я захочу свое приложение запустить на другом пк?

Comment: Создать аккаунт (либо расширить хост-часть у существующего) и дать соотв. права. Само собой, подключения по сети должны быть разрешены (disable_networking = OFF).

Comment: в моем приложении получается доступ идет от имени сервера порта логина и пароля админа субд

Comment: и у меня вопрос это надо бд саму импортировать в другой пк и менять хост и порт чтоб дать доступ к бд или есть вариант по легче?

Comment: самый нормальный способ - захостить базу данных, затем сделать вебсервис, который с ней будет работать (и также его захостить) и уже к этому сервису безопасно обращаться

Comment: если же вам просто "лабораторку на флешке принести и показать", то экспортируйте базу данных и импортируйте в воркбенч на нужном пк

Comment: можно пожалуйста ссылку на инфу как это сделать можно потому что я это впервые слышу

Comment: с хостингом базы данных всё просто: ищете хостинг ([вот бесплатный](https://remotemysql.com/login.php)), создаёте базу данных и работаете с этой базой данной. Её также можно подключить через воркбенч

Comment: веб-сервисы можно писать на APS.NET, [вот пример](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-mysql-with-asp-net-core/) как работать с MySQL

Comment: @iKuzmychov я попробую если возникнут еще вопросы можно к вам обратиться?

Comment: можете, а лучше, если что, задайте новый вопрос

Comment: @iKuzmychov я делаю приложение для диплома поэтому вот и такой вопрос я задавал так как не хочется постоянно импортировать бд

Comment: если для диплома, то забудьте про хостинг и сотальное, просто возпользуйтесь моими предыдущими советом про экспорт/импорт

Comment: @iKuzmychov а никак нельзя кинуть на хост существующую бд?

Comment: можно экспортировать и импортировать данные

Comment: @iKuzmychov а бд с workbench импортируется в phpmyadmin? в phpmyadmin есть сам mysql

Comment: @vlad_12 Workbench - это не база данных, это приложение, клиент базы данных. Оно ничем не хуже и не лучше того приложения, что пишете вы, так же к базе подключается, так же с ней работает. Не называйте базой таблички, которые на экране. База - это MySQL Server в данном случае. phpmyadmin - тоже клиент базы данных как и Workbench.